# Export limited data from cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I have a `Cassandra cluster C1` and `Cassandra cluster C2`, C1 has data in millions, i want to load only few data from C1 to C2, for example 100K. How can i export only 100K data among million of data in C1 and load that 100K data to C2 cluster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to write a custom application that does that; there is no way to do it using built-in tools.

The only exception I can think of, is if the data you'd like to import is contiguous, you may be able to copy over a limited set of SStables into the new cluster, and then trim away rows that don't belong by running `DELETE FROM` queries. But it's unclear whether that can save you any time in practice, because you'll have to specify each primary key to be deleted explicitly.